# Dummy ApplicationContext to test Filter in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm trying to test a filter I have, but I'm not sure how to configure SpringBootTest to use to it. Is there some way to provide a default/dummy ApplicationContext, as this project only contains the filter itself.

```java
package org.example.filters;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.mock.web.

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class LocaleFilterIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;

  @Test
  public void noLanguageShouldRedirectToSplash() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(get("/").contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)).andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error, as expected:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test.
```

Comment: there are many ways to load just that filter. you could create a `@SpringBootApplication` dummy class in that same package where the filter is (but in `src/test/java`) and thus the application will only scan that package

Comment: Yup that worked, thanks @Eugene!